# How to use nunjucks macros in the browser client-side?

Tags: javascript, node.js, nunjucks

I'm able to use client-side templating for nunjucks as I precompile from node.js and expose JS template files. I call the client-side templates like so:

```
nunjucks.render('partials/some-template.html', { abc: 123 })
```

and get a string back.

How can I call macros as I've tried but am doing this wrong. Macros are first declared on the page in terms of node.js then called successive times for example in Node.js:

```
{% include 'macros/checkbox.html' %}
...
{{ checkbox('you cool?', 'cool', false) }}
{{ checkbox('you collected?', 'collected', false) }}
```

But not sure how to get the macro then call it again and again in client-side. I did make an effort to go through the inspection in the console so far but no luck.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When I wanted to render a macro on the client side, I used the [nunjucks.renderString](https://mozilla.github.io/nunjucks/api.html#renderstring1) method to import the file containing the macros and then call it -- all in one go.  My usecase is rendering a macro into HTML, then adding it onto the page using Javascript.  A sample use case would be:

```
var renderString = "{% import 'packageForms.html' as forms %} \n";
renderString = renderString + '{{ form.packageForm("task") }}';
var renderedHTML = nunjucks.renderString(renderString);
$('#page').append(renderedHTML)
```

Comment: Keep in mind the 'slim' version doesn't have `renderString`